# Simplify this expression with modified Bessel functions of the second kind

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm interested in the function

$$\frac{K^{(0,2)}(0,x)}{K(0,x)}$$
where the numerator is the modified Bessel function of the second kind twice differentiated with respect to $\alpha$ and taken at $\alpha=0$.

An integral representation would be
$$\frac{\int_0^{\infty} t^2 e^{-x\cosh t}\mathrm{dt}}{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x\cosh t}\mathrm{dt}}$$

For $x \rightarrow \infty$ there's an asymptote in $1/(x+1/2)$ but that doesn't get me very far.

**I'd like to simplify this expression in a manner conducive to numerical calculation. I have a feeling numerically computing both the numerator and the denominator is innefficient as the ratio seems to be better behaved than either.**

Comment: Have a look at this paper by D. Amos on *computing ratios of modified Bessel functions of the first kind* (different topic but might give some ideas): http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-125/S0025-5718-1974-0333287-7/

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/